# Удаление поля из большой структуры (spark dataframe)

Tags: json, dataframe, struct, scala, apache-spark

Есть таблица, в полях вложенные структуры <array<struct ...>>

Например:

```json
{
"problems": [{
    "Diabetes":[{
        "medications":[{
            "medicationsClasses":[{
                "className":[{
                    "associatedDrug":[{
                        "name":"asprin",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"500 mg"
                    }],
                    "associatedDrug#2":[{
                        "name":"somethingElse",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"500 mg"
                    }]
                }],
                "className2":[{
                    "associatedDrug":[{
                        "name":"asprin",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"500 mg"
                    }],
                    "associatedDrug#2":[{
                        "name":"somethingElse",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"500 mg"
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }],
        "labs":[{
            "missing_field": "missing_value"
        }]
    }],
    "Asthma":[{}]
}]}
```

Необходимо удалить поле problems.Diabetes.medications.medicationsClasses.className.associatedDrug.dose

**Аналог:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727279/dropping-a-nested-column-from-spark-dataframe

1. В **Spark >= 3.1** есть функция dropFields, пробовал, не помогло (возможно из-за массивов).
2. Пробовал пересобрать структуру, но количество полей (примерно 2500) считаю большим для ручной переделки структуры. И не понятно как такое решение будет в prod работать. **(Пока единственное решение)**
3. Read JSON schema и spark.read.schema(schema).parquet(path) выдаёт ошибку.
4. Аналогично п.3 select(from_json(col, schema))

Была идея формировать JSON выходной файл и обрабатывать его различными библиотеками вроде fastjson. Но от решения отказался, т.к. файлов(строк в таблице) много.

**Подскажите, может есть ещё какие-то идеи или Вы сталкивались/решали подобный кейс?**

Comment: "Пробовал пересобрать структуру" -зачем пересобирать, прямо в ней запиши в поле null и сохрани

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено с помощью spark-hats, метод nestedDropColumn.

https://github.com/AbsaOSS/spark-hats